# Excel / VBA / Rows.Count return Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

The goal is to create a new entry to the Table via a Form. In the code I try to look for the last row in order to put the infromation into the blank field at the bottom. The Error 1004 appearse when i'm looking for the last row in the Table with the help of **Rows.Count**. This is the problem part:

```
iRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Row + 1
```

Here's the whole code:

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()

    Dim iRow As Long
    
    iRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Row + 1
    
    With Sheet1

        .Range("A" & iRow).Value = Me.txtName.Value
        
        'Gender
        
        If Me.optFemale.Value Then .Range("B" & iRow).Value = "Female"
        If Me.optMale.Value Then .Range("B" & iRow).Value = "Male"
        If Me.optUnknown.Value Then .Range("B" & iRow).Value = "Unknown"
        
        'Maritial Status
        
        If Me.optSingle.Value Then .Range("C" & iRow).Value = "Single"
        If Me.optMarried.Value Then .Range("C" & iRow).Value = "Married"
        If Me.optOther.Value Then .Range("C" & iRow).Value = "Other"

    End With
    
    'Reset the controls after submitting
    
    Me.txtName.Value = ""
    Me.optFemale.Value = False
    Me.optMale.Value = False
    Me.optUnknown.Value = False
    Me.optSingle.Value = False
    Me.optMarried.Value = False
    Me.optOther.Value = False
    
    MsgBox "Data submitted Successfully!"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `x1Up` - you have a digit 1 whereas it should be a lower case L `l`.

Comment: Problem solved! You're my saviour. Thank you alot.